# using case 0: in q to change delimiters in a file in q coding

Tags: kdb

I am given a file path and an old parameter to change to a new one, I am trying to use case 0 for the first time, perhaps  `sv would work. I have saved the file as`:tbl.csv and would want to call a function to change it from "," to "|". Although tbl.csv exists I get an error for using:

```
"|" 0:`:tbl
```

But I can use

```
"|" 0:tbl
```

why can not use the full file path name? Is there a better method for changing delimiters in a file?

Comment: I can see there is the ssr[X;Y;Z] where X is the string with Y and Z the replacing strings, but does not seem to work on a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0:` can do several different operations depending on your inputs.

`"|" 0: tbl` will take your q table, `tbl`, and output a list of character strings containing text representation of the rows of `tbl` separated by "|".

Once you have this output you can overwrite your csv using `0:` by using the file handle as the left argument:

```
`:tbl.csv 0: "|" 0: tbl
```

That's great if you're staring with `tbl` in memory, but if you're starting with the csv and don't want to read it in as a q table first then you can read it in using `read0`, replace all commas with pipes using `ssr`, and overwrite the csv using `0:`:

```
`:tbl.csv 0: ssr[;",";"|"] each read0 `:tbl.csv
```

Comment: `ssr` could give incorrect results if there's commas in escaped strings inside the csv. May be worth considering with the second example above.

Comment: can we use `:tbl.csv 0: to change the file property and extension to a different format?

Comment: `0:` does not modify files. It can read a text file into a q table and write text to a file. So if you wan to change the delimiter you will have to read, modify, and overwrite it as above.
So far as the file extension goes you can simply use a different extension in your file handle:

`\`:tbl.txt 0: ssr[;",";"|"] each read0 \`:tbl.csv`
This will create the file tbl.txt, but will not remove tbl.csv. You will have to remove the old file yourself.